# Vbscript method GetAbsolutePathName() in HTML do not return the current path of the HTML document

Tags: html, vbscript

Hi all I can't understand why GetAbsolutePathName() in HTML does not return the current path of the HTML document it returns to me the only Desktop path

[image]

if I run the same cod as .vbs all work perfectly it returns to me a real path and doesn't matter in which directory I run this script

Ran from .vbs desktop

[image]

Ran from another directory

[image]

```
Option Explicit

dim fs,path
set fs= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
path=fs.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

MsgBox path
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this. It's "almost" the same but I don't know why it works so smoothly, giving me back the whole path of the file

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Ruta1=(fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName))&"\"

MsgBox ruta1
```

Comment: It works because it's based on the script location (`WScript.ScriptFullName`) instead of the current working directory (`.`). Those two are not identical.

Comment: You are absolutely right Ansgar , when you say it is based on the location of the .vbs file not the file you want its path, thank you for the comment and clarification.